# How do I tell how many gold pieces I've grabbed in a Retro Level?

Tags: runner2

I'm looking to perfect the entire game and would to know if there is a way to tell how many gold pieces you've grabbed on a retro level. The game only marks the level with a star after you beat it, but doesn't actually show you a ratio of gold pieces you've grabbed in the level.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer with screen shot: "[Is there some reason to get all the gold in the retro levels?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106997/is-there-some-reason-to-get-all-the-gold-in-the-retro-levels)"

tl;dr: the only place retro-gold seems to count is on the main map, in the lower-left "Totalés Grandé".  No way to distinguish which level the gold is *from*, but the retro levels do contribute towards the total.